# wix setup does not install VS 2005 merge module files

Tags: wix, setup-project, merge-module

it might be a stupid question, but i've spent few hours testing various possibilities and didn't find the answer.

I have one standard merge module prepared in VS 2005 (its probably fine, i've prepared standard VS 2005 setup project, included the merge module and it worked properly)

Wix project(mainly because GUI reasons) to take care about the installation. Code samples(shortened for brevity)

Directories part:

```
<Directory Id="INSTALLLOCATION" Name="sth">
      <Merge Id='MyModule3' Language='1033' SourceFile='MergeModule.msm' DiskId='1' />
</Directory>
```

Feature part:

```
<Feature Id="ProductFeature3" Title="Tit" Level="1" Description='Yeah' ConfigurableDirectory='INSTALLLOCATION' Display='expand'
         AllowAdvertise='no'>
  <MergeRef Id='MyModule3' />
  <ComponentGroupRef Id="Product.Generated" />
</Feature>
```

After building WIX project it throws errors like:

> ICE83: Both MsiPublishAssemblies AND MsiUnpublishAssemblies actions MUST be present in InstallExecuteSequence table.
>   ICE83: The MsiPublishAssemblies action MUST be present in AdvtExecuteSequence table.

I've added lines:

```
<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="PreventDowngrading"
     After="FindRelatedProducts">NEWPRODUCTFOUND</Custom> //i suppose it doesnt influence nothing here
  <MsiPublishAssemblies Sequence="1502" />
  <MsiUnpublishAssemblies Sequence="1501" />
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

And:

```
 <AdvertiseExecuteSequence>
  <MsiPublishAssemblies Sequence="1502" />
</AdvertiseExecuteSequence>
```

After that buildling process doesn't return any errors, but despite installing the feature (selected on feature list) there are no feature files on the HDD. I think it might be caused by Sequence numbers but i haven't got any ideas how to fix them, anyone can help?

If more info is needed i'll surely provide it.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a number of things that can go wrong.  I'd look at the install log to see if the files got installed, just not where you were expecting them to get installed.   I've known VDPROJ MSM's to have a great many problems including authoring their directory tables incorrectly.

You might want to look at an open source project that I created called IsWiX (CodePlex.com).  It's designed be a UI authoring tool for WiX Merge Module projects that also allows you the raw ability to add additional metadata using traditional WiX XML.   The result is a very clean merge module that can be consumed by InstallShield, WiX, VDPROJ, et al.

Comment: I've looked through install log and the first thing that came suspicious to is a whole series of entries(during component register)like:
`MSI (s) (0C:E8) [07:50:17:554]: WIN64DUALFOLDERS: Substitution in 'C:\Program Files (x86)\ChosenDir\Module Retargetable Folder\test.dll' folder had been blocked by the 1 mask argument (the folder pair's iSwapAttrib member = 0).`

Any ideas what to do with that or maybe more information needed ?